# Ansible: Further plays are not executing if task in one play failed when multiple plays in a playbook

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with multiple plays as below,

```
- name: play1
  hosts: host1
  tasks:
  - command: dgfdgd
- name: play2
  hosts: host2
  tasks:
  - command: ls
```

the output I'm getting as below,

```
PLAY [play1] *****************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************
ok: [10.15.23.76]

TASK [command] ***************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.15.23.76]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "dgfdgd", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************
10.155.23.76               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I want both the plays to execute even if one play failed to execute. If I use ignore_errors: yes, it executes but I also want the failed one to be displayed in the PLAY RECAP summary.

Any support on this please.

Comment: That's what [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks) (and rescue) is for.

Comment: how do we get the count for errors if we add them to rescued ? is there a way to get the failed counts ?

Comment: See `PLAY RECAP`. One of the reported parameters is `rescued=0`. It's possible to use [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/) to read [stdout](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy). Next option is to sun the playbook from [Python](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_interface.html#runner-stdout) and read [stdout](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_interface.html#runner-stdout).

Comment: There is also a simple option to increment a variable in the rescue section.

Comment: @VladimirBotka, dont we have a native feature of ansible to continue with other subsequent plays if task in one play failed to execute ? I thought this is a functionality in ansible with with multiple plays in place ?

Comment: Yes. There are other options. See [Error Handling in Playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#error-handling-in-playbooks).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use *block* and *rescue*. For example the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- name: play1
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - command: /bin/true
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            my_rescued: "{{ my_rescued|default(0)|int + 1 }}"
    - block:
        - command: /bin/false
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            my_rescued: "{{ my_rescued|default(0)|int + 1 }}"
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- name: play2
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - command: /bin/false
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            my_rescued: "{{ my_rescued|default(0)|int + 1 }}"
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
- name: play3
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - command: /bin/true
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            my_rescued: "{{ my_rescued|default(0)|int + 1 }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_rescued
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_rescued: '2'

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************
localhost: ok=5 changed=2 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=2 ignored=0
```

---

> Q: *"Is there a way to add my_rescued to failed count ?"*

A: `PLAY RECAP` statistics values are not available at the playbooks' level. Such evaluation of the playbooks' result should be done outside the playbook. For example in a script, AWX, [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) etc.

For example the script below

```sh
shell> cat playbook.sh
#!/bin/bash
out=$(ansible-playbook playbook.yml 2>&1 | tail -2)
host=$(echo $out | cut -d ':' -f 1 | xargs)
results=$(echo $out | cut -d ':' -f 2)
ok=$(echo $results | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -d '=' -f 2)
changed=$(echo $results | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d '=' -f 2)
unreachable=$(echo $results | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d '=' -f 2)
failed=$(echo $results | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | cut -d '=' -f 2)
skipped=$(echo $results | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | cut -d '=' -f 2)
rescued=$(echo $results | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cut -d '=' -f 2)
ignored=$(echo $results | cut -d ' ' -f 7 | cut -d '=' -f 2)
printf "$host: ok=$ok changed=$changed unreachable=$unreachable \
failed=$failed skipped=$skipped rescued=$rescued ignored=$ignored\n"
```

gives

```
shell> ./playbook.sh 
localhost: ok=5 changed=2 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=2 ignored=0
```

Comment: is there a way to add my_rescued to failed count ?

Comment: by the way thanks for this approach. i'm on my last leg. If I get a way to add the my_rescued count to failed count in the PLAY RECAP then I'm done.

Comment: I've added an example of a script. You're welcome. Open a new question if you have other problems.

Comment: Thank you so much @vladimir. really helpful. we have implemented with block and rescue model.